# Security implications of adding DirectorySlash Off to .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've built an API and I was having problems when sending POST requests to http://localhost/api/messages.  I would get a 301 saying moved permanently to http://localhost/api/messages/ (note the forward slash).  I fixed this by adding `DirectorySlash Off` to my `.htaccess` file.

However I read somewhere that this is may cause security implications as this is normally turned on?  Do I need to add `.htaccess` into any other directories within my API and do `DirectorySlash On`?